# Firebase app invites link in email not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, invite, deeplink

I have implemented `firebase` invites to my `android` app as follows:

- Firebase Console: ok
- Dynamic links: enabled
- App has well formed `google_services.json`
- I use `AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder` which is sending e-mails and SMS-s as expected
- I have my app on `Google Play` in alpha testing

BUT

None of the email or SMS link works.
It is formed like this:

> `https://[appname].page.link/i/[app-id][invitation-id]`

If I change `/i/` in the above link to the char sequence of the short dynamic link and `?` it works fine.
But it would be more than great to enable users not doing this :)

Comment: I also found that I have 2 different client ids under the same project, same package name in Google API console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same problem but was able to fix it by deleting the Firebase project and creating a new one. The original project was automatically created by the Firebase Assistant in Android Studio (which displayed an error although the project was created). I created the new one manually.

After the manual procedure, many APIs were automatically enabled in Google API Console including `Firebase Dynamic Links API` and `Firebase Services API`, which you could try enabling before deleting the project.

However, it seems that in the Dynamic Links section in Firebase Console, you should have a domain name in the form `https://[random].app.goo.gl`. The Invite links then use this domain. I had the links in the form you posted previously, those didn't work. So if you can't see it there, the easiest solution (if you can afford to do it) is to delete the project and create a new one.

Comment: Thank you very much for the useful answer. And you were right: I have set up a brand new project and app with the same content. It took me a little more work than expected but it works. Would be good to have a better developer documentation from Google.